# GetX controller not refreshing the content on the UI even though my state is updating

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using GetX in my app and I am also a beginner to GetX. I have some code in my controller and my UI listens to that state by wrapping around it with a `Obx(() => myWidget)`. Eventually my UI does not update even when my state changes and I am printing the changes in my console too.

This is my controller

```
class MyController extends GetxController {
      RxList<String> topicsDummyList = <String>[
    'Career',
    'computer',
    'science',
    'art',
    'creative',
    'axim',
  ].obs;

  RxList<String> searchTopicsList = <String>[].obs;

  void searchTopicsListHandler(String val) {
    if (!val.isBlank!) {
      searchTopicsList.value = topicsDummyList
          .where(
            (String e) => e.toLowerCase().contains(
                  val.toLowerCase(),
                ),
          )
          .toList();
    }
  }

}
```

This is my View(UI) too

```
 Obx(() {
   return customFilterField(
      type: MentorFilterType.TOPIC,
      hintText: 'Topic/Mentorship focus',
      selectedList: controller.selectedTopicsList,
      searchHintText: 'Search topics',

      // THIS IS WHERE I AM LISTENING TO THE STATE
      dummyList: controller.searchTopicsList.isEmpty
                  ? controller.topicsDummyList
                    : controller.searchTopicsList,
      onEnd: (_) {
            controller.searchTopicsList.clear();
          });
       }),
```

THIS IS THE `customFilterField` ITS SELF

```
Widget customFilterField({
    required String hintText,
    required List selectedList,
    required String searchHintText,
    required List dummyList,
    required MentorFilterType type,
    required Function(dynamic result)? onEnd,
  }) {
    return Obx(
      () => CustomTextFieldWidget(
        key: ValueKey(selectedList),
        onTap: () {
          Utils.customBottomSheet(
            onEnd: onEnd,
            child: Obx(
              () => Column(
                children: [
                  verticalSpaceSmallY,
                  CustomTextFieldWidget(
                    onChanged: (val) {
                            controller.searchTopicsListHandler(
                              val!,
                            );
                          }
                    hintText: searchHintText,
                    prefixIcon: SvgPicture.asset(AppImages.searchSvg),
                    fillColor: Get.theme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    borderColor: AppColors.tinygrey,
                    borderRadius: 30,
                    validator: null,
                  ).paddingSymmetric(
                    horizontal: 18.w,
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.w),
                    itemCount: dummyList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Obx(
                        () => CustomListTileWidget(
                          contentpadding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.w),
                          onTap: () {
                                  controller.topicsSelectedHandler(
                                    dummyList[index],
                                  );
                                }
                          titleWidget: CustomText(
                            text: dummyList[index],
                            font: Dimens.fontSize15,
                            txtAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            fntweight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                          trailing: Container(
                            height: 15,
                            width: 15,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              border: selectedList.contains(dummyList[index])
                                  ? null
                                  : Border.all(),
                            ),
                            child: selectedList.contains(dummyList[index])
                                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                                    AppImages.select,
                                  )
                                : null,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                  verticalSpaceMediumX,
                  CustomElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    title: 'Continue',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        initialValue: selectedList.length == 1
            ? selectedList.first
            : selectedList.length >= 2
                ? '${selectedList.length} topics selected'
                : null,
        readOnly: true,
        borderRadius: 5,
        hintText: hintText,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is not my project...I came to meet the project in the company

Comment: Wrap your ListView.builder in the customFilterField Widget with GetBuilder and call update() from listener function in the controller.